# Non-commutative version of the order dimension of a poset

Tags: order-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, posets

I view the *order dimension* of a poset $P$ as an inherently commutative notion. On the one hand, it can be defined via realizers, which I find fairly intuitive from an order-theoretic viewpoint. On the other hand, the order dimension is known to be equivalent to the minimal $k$ such that $P$ has an order-embedding into $\mathbb{N}^k$.

Taking the latter statement as the definition, we can generalize it to a non-commutative version: For a poset $P$, define the non-commutative version of the order-dimension $\operatorname{ncdim}(P)$ to be the minimal $k$ such that $P$ has an order-embedding into a (possibly non-commutative) monoid of $k$ generators. Hereby, the partial order of the monoid is induced by left- or right-factorization, analogously to what we think of in $\mathbb{N}^k$.

To make it more interesting, one could also demand the resulting monoid to have some additional properties, such as cancellativity. Maybe it makes sense to restrict to finite posets, or, later, to investigate if the restriction to lattices simplifies the theory.

Anyway, one can ask some natural questions:

1. Is there a general bound for $\operatorname{ncdim}(P)$, depending on the additional properties of the monoid?
2. Is it possible to give a concrete order-embedding into a monoid of  $\operatorname{ncdim}(P)$ generators that could be understood as "most simple" or "canonical" in some sense?
3. Is there hope to determine $\operatorname{ncdim}(P)$, probably with some polynomial algorithm?

(and more of course.)

Does anyone know about any research in this direction? Any references or thoughts are highly appreciated!

Comment: Every countable monoid embeds into a monoid on 2 generators.  So I'd guess the only countable values taken by this number are $0,1,2$. For the poset structure, you maybe mean left-factorization only (of  course right-factorization leads to the same definition, but I'm not sure whether you're considering a mixture of the two).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So we would use the order dimension for that construction. Also in that case, question 2 may still be interesting. But I am not sure if that statement still holds true if we restrict to cancellative monoids, however.

Comment: I guess the embedding result still holds for cancellative monoids (to be confirmed).

Comment: Oh, but thinking twice, a monoid embedding need not be a poset embedding (it's typically false for an embedding into a group). So one could ask whether every countable monoid embeds into a 2-generated one in a way that preserves, say, the left-factorization partial ordering ("preserves" meaning $i(x)\le i(y)$ iff $x\le y$).

Comment: Exactly. That's what I am looking for. Just wondering if I have to start from scratch or if there is already some research out there.